# Converting ReactJS app to traditional HTML/CSS/JS - handling dynamic data

Tags: reactjs, render-to-string

I'm trying to convert a ReactJS app I developed into traditional HTML/CSS/JS code. Using React's renderToString allows me to generate static code, but for situations where data needs to be fetched from the server and rendered dynamically, it does not work as expected. This is because renderToString generates purely static code without the ability to call AJAX endpoints.
could you please analyze potential solutions for this issue?

Some key points I would highlight:
The challenge of converting React's dynamic rendering to static HTML/CSS/JS
Using renderToString works for static content, but not for dynamic data needing real-time updates
Fetching data from the server at runtime to inject into HTML
Preserving React's interactivity and dynamic capabilities when converting to traditional web technologies

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.